# How to get values from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Coffee" [1]=> string(4) "best" }
```

How can I get the values from it like Coffe, best?

Comment: This is thoroughly covered [in the PHP Array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), sarting with the section _Example #6 Accessing array elements_

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fundamental basics that the manual covers.

Comment: Unless this is about finding the index that goes with `"Coffee"` and `"best"` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access arrays using their index. Array indexes in PHP start at 0 and count up.

```
$myArray = array("Coffee","best");
$coffee = $myArray[0];
$best = $myArray[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

That is an more difficult approach to declaring the array

```
<?php

array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Coffee" [1]=> string(4) "best" }

$arrayname['Key']; //access

?>
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your post, to mark the code up properly - if you click the `{}` icon, or indent it with four spaces, it'll appear correctly.